# Change Font Size of Single Tick Matplotlib Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, seaborn

I have a graph where the x tick labels are pretty large strings. I was able to make the font size a good size where it isn't an eyesore, but one of the labels is a much longer string than any of the others. I do not want to change the font size of all ticks, because it will be hard to read. I just want to change the one tick. Depending on the data I plot, this tick not always in the same location on the graph(ticks are not always in the same order, it is a bar graph), but the name of the tick is always `Underneath Screen`, if that is helpful for any examples.

Answer (score 2):

this would work

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3]
y = [2,4.5,4]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks([1,2,3], ['this', 'is', 'custom'])

font_sizes = [10,20,30]

for tick, size in zip(plt.xticks()[-1], font_sizes):
    tick.set_fontsize(size)
```

[image]